# Starting jetty fail in ubuntu 14

Tags: solr, jetty, ubuntu-14.04, cloud9

I install the solr-jetty package in a Ubuntu 14 container running in a cloud9 workspace.

To install the package I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install solr-jetty
```

The installation doesn't return any error.
Then I try to start solr with the following command:

```
sudo service jetty start
```

But I receive the following error:

```
 * Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty
 * Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://host-solr-3694477:8983/. jetty
   ...fail!
```

In the log file of jetty I get the following message:

```
failed setting default capabilities.
set_caps(CAPS) failed for user 'jetty'
Service exit with a return value of 4
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This seems like a better question for serverfault.com

Comment: Have you tried instaling `apache2-utils` which contains rotatelogs?

Comment: @MatsLindh the problem is not in the rotatelogs: not found. I already correct that problem applying this fix: http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2016-06/msg16756.html. Correcting this the "...fail!" message still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the problem I had to change the user that run jetty from jetty to root. 
This can be configured by editing the `/etc/default/jetty` file.
I think it is not the more correct solution because it can add security problems. If anyone have a better solution ...

Answer (score 2):

Docker user here, same problem, but - this worked for me (and this is as unadvised as changing the user to 'root', suggested above):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Set the following on your 'docker run' command when creating a container:

--privileged=true

I'm just using docker for development, so not overly concerned yet with the security implications of this.